# JSON array error

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have the following JSON file (rectangles.json):

```
{  
   "rectangles":[  
   {  
     "x":0,
     "y":0,
     "width":20,
     "height":10,
     "color":"red"
  },
  {  
     "x":25,
     "y":0,
     "width":20,
     "height":10,
     "color":"red"
  }
]
}
```

I get the following error: `'Unexpected Token :' on line 2.` I can't figure out the issue. Any suggestions? 
Below is the javascript I have in a local file:

```
function load(){
 var myData = JSON.parse(rectangles);
 var can = document.getElementById('rectangleCanvas');
 var context = can.getContext('2d');

 for (i=0; i<myData.length; i++){
  context.fillStyle = myData[i].color;
  context.fillRect(myData[i].x, myData[i].y, myData[i].width, myData[i].height);
} 
}
```

And her is my HTML from another local file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Fetch JSON array Data</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="rectangles.json"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="rectangleCanvas" width="22528" height="20922"></canvas> 
<script>load();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong either. [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.com) says it's valid as well. I have a feeling it's going wrong somewhere else. Could you post your code that leads up to this error?

Comment: @D.Visser I added myjavascript and html to my original post.

Comment: if you use this json in console then it will give you error use var xyz =yourJson same in your javascript code you have to use variable

Comment: So I declare my json file as a veriable in my javascript? But how do i fetch the external json file to begin with?

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="rectangles.json"></script>
> ```

JSON is a data format inspired by JavaScript literal syntax. It is, however, **not** JavaScript. You can't load it using a `<script>` element. You need to either:

1. Write some JavaScript to fetch the JSON using, for example, the `XMLHttpRequest` object (this is commonly known as Ajax).
2. Change the JSON to a JavaScript program that creates a global variable you can access
3. Change the JSON to a JavaScript program that calls a function and passes the data as an argument

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Would you happen to know why Netbeans is throwing a 'Syntax error: Unexpected Token ':'' on line 2 of my JSON file?

Comment: @Mike — Because it is trying to treat it as JavaScript, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get such an error if you're trying to evaluate your JSON file as JavaScript. I copied and pasted your string into the Chrome console and got the same error. But, if I set that JSON string to a variable it works:

```
    var awesomeRect = {  
       "rectangles":[  
    {  
      "x":0,
      "y":0,
      "width":20,
      "height":10,
      "color":"red"
   },
   {  
      "x":25,
      "y":0,
      "width":20,
      "height":10,
      "color":"red"
   }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: I pasted this into a JSON editor and it says that it is not valid. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes this is expected because once you add the `var awesomeRect =` line it is no longer valid as a json file

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON file looks fine so you might probably try to parse the object which is already a JSON format after you read it from file.

For example if you read it from file and say you store it in a variable `rect`:

```
var rect = {  
    "rectangles":[  
    {  
        "x":0,
        "y":0,
        "width":20,
        "height":10,
        "color":"red"
    },
    {  
       "x":25,
       "y":0,
       "width":20,
       "height":10,
       "color":"red"
    }
    ]
}
```

If you parse that such variable `rect` again, you'll get an error.

```
JSON.parse(rect); // throw you an error: Unexpected token
```

Because the variable is already a JSON format.